# Compare 24hr Strings with Java

Tags: java, datetime

I have the following String representation of 24hr like `1423` and `1956`

I would like to check if the current time (with time zone) is between this pair

my current solution gets the hour and minute of the day using

```
int h = Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getHour()
int t = Instant.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).getMinute()
```

creating a 4 digit strings from the numbers, and do a string comparison

I don't like my solution at all, What's the elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert String representation of time to `LocalTime` as follows:

```
var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmm");
var lowerTime = LocalTime.parse("1423", formatter);
var upperTime = LocalTime.parse("1956", formatter);
```

Then you can use `isAfter()`/`isBefore` methods to check if it is in between:

```
var nowTime = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
boolean inBetween = nowTime.isAfter(lowerTime) && nowTime.isBefore(upperTime);
```

Comment: Oof, well played, same time! (you beat me by a few seconds)

Comment: first is first :) loved the use of `var`!

Answer (score 5):

Create a LocalTime object using the ZonedDateTime.now() reference and subsequent call to ZonedDateTime#toLocalTime. Then create a DateTimeFormatter object using the Pattern **HHmm** which stands for hours (HH) and minutes (mm). Then you can create a LocalTime from the start time 1423 using the pattern, and an end time  of 1956 from the pattern. You can then create a boolean representing whether or not your time is between by determining if the current time is after the start time and before the end time.

```java
    LocalTime time = ZonedDateTime.now().toLocalTime();

    DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmm");

    LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.parse("1423", pattern);

    LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.parse("1956", pattern);

    boolean between = time.isAfter(startTime) && time.isBefore(endTime);
```

Comment: Yeah, just realized it's more implicit, my bad!

Comment: @YCF_L Haha, you're keeping me on point today, thanks, i'll edit now :P

Answer (score 1):

As you note in the question, your strings are in 24-hour time with leading zeros, so you can compare them as strings. Here is a more convenient way to convert the current time to a string in the required format:

```java
String now = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmm")
                              .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                              .format(Instant.now());
```

Comment: While it works, it’s better and clearer to compare `LocalTime` (or other date-time) objects.

Comment: Why is it better or clearer? This is the reason for having leading zeros in the string representation.

Comment: On the other hand this is why we have date and time data types. Which do you find clearer, `time.isAfter(startTime)` or `now.compareTo(startTimeString) > 0`? Which is simpler? Would you also prefer `"7".compareTo("3") > 0` over `7 > 3`?

Comment: Comparing the strings is a bad habit to get into because it doesn’t always work correctly, and these are not the easiest bugs to spot.

Comment: Comparing strings does work correctly if you are using a string representation designed such that string comparison gives the correct result. It is not a bad habit to use such string representations, nor to take advantage of their design. I would rather write the simpler code using strings and `compareTo` with a comment explaining why it is correct, than the longer code creating more objects that takes more time to read than the other code and comment combined. Either way, any bug will be spotted by the unit tests.